# Why can't I still move/delete long file paths in Windows Explorer after enabling the Group Policy in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, delete-file, windows-10-desktop

I have a source code folder with a lot of files and subfolders nested in it. Windows 10 can now supposedly handle long file paths via the Group Policy Editor. I've enabled it already and restarted my computer multiple times.

[image]

But trying to delete the source code folder still give this error.

[image]

Does anyone know how exactly the new Group Policy works? I was assuming it would work on Windows Explorer itself. I'm using 64-bit Pro Windows 10.

Comment: This should probably be on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked Microsoft employee [Gov Maharaj](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show) and the feature is not ready to be enabled for Windows Explorer in Windows 10 1607 and 1703. So you still have the issue with Explorer. You have to wait until Microsoft enables it for Explorer or use a 3rd party file management tool which is compatible with the long paths and has the setting

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

set in its manifest file. If this setting is set, it can use the long paths, but Explorer still doesn't have this entry.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bummer. I was excited too.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 Pro 1709 build and still having the same issue as OP. Can you confirm if Explorer has been fixed to resolve the issue for 1709 build?

Comment: @Zythyr no it is still not fixed even in last RS4 Insider builds.